# How can I do this in PHP / http post?

Tags: php, api, http-post

I have been given API documentation which I don't quite get as there is no URL to connect up to?

http://support.planetdomain.com/index.php?_m=downloads&_a=viewdownload&downloaditemid=14&nav=0

I'd prefer doing this in PHP..

How can I run a 10 iteration loop, doing a check if domain is available, if it's response is available, then perform the register command and exit the script (using the code provided in thd documentation).

Thank you.

Comment: @silent: I just needed direction so I could learn to do this on my own :)

Comment: Give it an attempt and come back when you get stuck. Stack Overflow isn't about writing your code for you.

Comment: Do you know whether they have any other documentation?  "All the Information you need about setting up the API" is a little generous in the description of that PDF.

Comment: @J_C: StackOverflow is about members of the community helping you to create your own solution. So, have you written any code for this problem yet? If so, share it in your question. Are you getting error messages? If so, what are they? Again, show them in your question. Asking a very broad question like this looks more like a request for someone else to do the work for you, which, as @silent mentioned, would be better suited to one of the freelance job-boards out there.

Comment: that PDF has rich of information. you just need to sent parameter using POST and parse the returning XML.

Comment: @silent, @Lucanos, @Cole, @meagar: Thank you - will try and do this on my own and come back if I have any issues.. which I'm sure I will but as you guys said, best to attempt it then come back for help with any issues/errors. Thanks! :)

Comment: The API Server Address is "https://api.planetdomain.com/servlet/TLDServlet" (According to http://support.planetdomain.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=77)

Answer (score 0):

For the basics, I suggest using [cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php) to access resources by HTTP POST.

I put this into a function:

```
function api_call($url,$data,$timeout=20)
  {
  $response=false;

  $ch=curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt_array($ch,array(CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER=>true,CURLOPT_NOBODY=>false,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT=>$timeout,CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE=>1,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT=>1,CURLOPT_POST=>true));


  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);//this is an array containing the data you're sending them - an associative array describing which call.

  //data example:
  //array('operation'=>'user.verify','admin.username'=>'you','admin.password'=>'pass','reseller.id'=>'xxx') 

  $response=curl_exec($ch);

  $status_code=intval(curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
  curl_close($ch);

  return array('status'=>$status_code,'url'=>$url,'data'=>$response);
  }
```

However, you need to supply a URL. Lucanos noted in the comments it is  "api.planetdomain.com/servlet/TLDServlet".

http://support.planetdomain.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=77

by the way, I only use cURL for GET requests, so I might be missing some details on how to do a POST right. I tried to fill it in, though.

You ask "How can I run a 10 iteration loop, doing a check if domain is available, if it's response is available, then perform the register command and exit the script (using the code provided in thd documentation)."

Well, here's some pseudocode mixed with valid PHP. I don't know the domainplanet API as you know, so this will NOT work as is but it should give you a decent idea about it.

```
 for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    {
    //set up the domain check call
    $domains=array('futunarifountain.co.uk','megahelicopterunicornassaultlovepageant.ly');
    $domain_check_call=array('domain.name'=>$domains[$i]);
    $domain_info=api_call($dp_base_url,$domain_check_call);

    $info=json_decode($domain_info,true);//IF they use JSON and not XML or something

    if($info['domain']['status']=='available')
        {
        $register_call=something();//make the API calls to register the domain, similar to the above
        if($register_call['success']){ exit();/*or whatever*/ }
        }

    }
```

Hope that helps get you on the right track.